# Is there an efficient way to override CSS-Variables(CSS Custom Properties) from Bootstrap5 via CDN?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, css-variables, custom-properties

I include Bootstrap5 via CDN like this:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

[Link where I found this code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#css)

**My goal:**
I want to change the colors of my **bootstrap colors** from the **default-blue** to some **red-tone**.
Sounds easy, right?
Well it´s not: If you first include boostrap CDN and then your own css (as you should) and add the code

`--bs-secondary: rgb(243, 113, 33)`

the color of `.btn-secondary` does not change.

In order to change the color from `.btn-secondary` I would have to manually change the css of this class. This can be quite inefficient if you want to change 5 colors or other variables.

**My Question therefore is:**
*Is there an easy way to override custom properties (=css variables) with Bootstrap5 via CDN?*

Comment: Where are you adding the code?

Comment: No, not using CSS variables. Basically, CSS variables are read-only. You can use them to create new classes but not change the existing Bootstrap classes. Customizing Bootstrap  colors requires SASS or a lot of custom CSS.